# Mac OS X /usr/bin/time verbose flag

Tags: macos, bash, time, terminal

I have been trying to run the `usr/bin/time` command in my terminal (Bash) with the verbose flag `--verbose` or `-v` but have repeatedly been getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/time: illegal option -- v
usage: time [-lp] command.
```

The command I have been running looks like basically like this:

```
/usr/bin/time -v python practice.py
```

Any ideas how to get this to work properly on a Mac? (I have OS X Yosemite)?

Comment: As you can plainly see from the output when using an illegal option the only options BSD time supports are shown in the error message!

Comment: MacOS X compiled time not support -v because it's a builtin command and those not support otion -v.

Comment: @abkrim, David A is not using the `builtin time`, he's using `BSD time`, `/usr/bin/time`, which is not the same as the `builtin time` only supports the `-p` _option_. Neither of these support the `-v` _option_ and If he needs the `-v` _option_ then he'll have to install `GNU time` by one means or another. I installed it directly from [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/time/) using Command Line Tools for Xcode, without having to use homebrew or macports... both of which require Command Line Tools for Xcode be installed anyway.

Comment: Uhmm.. I use XCode with Command Line Tools, latest version and time version on my MacosX it's not GNU Time (man time show BSD General Commands Manual)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you have homebrew, you can get GNU `time` by installing the `gnu-time` package:

```
brew install gnu-time
```

After that, it’s available as the `gtime` command:

```
$ gtime
Usage: gtime [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--help] command [arg...]
```

The case is similar for a lot of other homebrew-packaged GNU utilities for OSX; e.g., you can get the GNU `df` command with `gdf`, `du` with `gdu`, `readlink` with `greadlink`, etc.

The homebrew package that has most of those is `coreutils`, which installs about a hundred different GNU-flavored commands. Other useful packages: `findutils`, `gnu-sed`, `gnu-tar`.

If you don’t have homebrew installed yet, you can get it with just a single command:

**Command to download and install homebrew**

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL\
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think looking at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) the verbose flag is GNU only. Unfortunately, OSX implementation simply differs.